# Delete Item from Array and Update (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Trying to Delete an Item from a Array **but it is not updating**

```
const todoList = ["wake up", "brush", "code", "eat"];
const [todo, setTodo] = useState(todoList);

const handleDelete = (idx) => {
 todoList.splice(idx, 1); // ["wake up", "code", "eat"]
 setTodo(todoList); // Does not Change `todo`
}

<ul>
{todo.map((todo, index) => (<li key={index}>{todo}<span className="materialsymbols-outlined" onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>delete</span></li>))}
</ul>
```

im Struggling on this for 3 hrs, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `handleDelete` method so that it filters a removed index and creates a new array with a new reference, for example:

```
  const handleDelete = (idx) => {
    const filteredTodos = todo.filter((_, index) => index !== idx);
    setTodo(filteredTodos);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `todoList` reference to update the state as `splice` delete an element from the `array` but keep the reference, Also I suggest using `setState` callback.

```
const handleDelete = (idx) => {
 setTodo(prev => {
  prev.splice(idx, 1)
  return [...prev]
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do something like this:

```
const todoList = ["wake up", "brush", "code", "eat"];
const [todo, setTodo] = useState(todoList);

const handleDelete = (idx) => {
 let arr = [...todoList];
 arr.splice(idx, 1);
 setTodo(arr);
}
```

This should normally work. Hope it helps!!!